# Can I animate this image diagonally across the screen on scroll and slower than the window?

Tags: javascript, image, scroll

I am trying to make this image animate across the screen from the top left to the bottom right as I scroll down the page. I would really love to have the image scroll slower than the page so that it will be on screen the whole time. I looked into paralax but am unsure if this is the best solution. Bonus points if there was a way to make it start smaller, then get bigger as it scrolls down, giving it the appearance of coming closer from far away.

[Here](https://jonalden.github.io/JonAldenPortfolio/) is a link to the page as as it's working now for reference:

**HTML**

```
<section class="astronaut">
    <img src="assets/Images/astronaut_PNG69.png" alt="astronaut" 
    class="astronautImage">
</section>`
```

**JavaScript**

```
let current = $(window).scrollTop();
const total = $(window).height() - current;
const ele = $(".astronautImage");
const currPosition = ele.position().left;
const trackLength = 250;
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    current = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log({ total: total, current: current });
    console.log(current / total * 100);
    const newPosition = trackLength * (current / total)
    ele.css({ left: currPosition + newPosition * (8) + 'px' });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using css transform looks more easy and will render smooth animation of what you are trying to accomplish. This is an idea to get you started, just apply some percentages to scale and translate to make it consistent

```js
var measure = {
  totalY: document.body.scrollHeight,
  totalX: document.body.scrollWidth,
  screenY: screen.height,
  screenX: screen.width,
}

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  const posY = $(this).scrollTop();
  const pos = {
    x: measure.screenX / measure.totalY * posY + 'px',
    y: posY + (measure.screenY / measure.totalY * posY) + 'px',
  };
  $('img').css('transform', `translate(${pos.x},${pos.y}) scale(${(1 + posY / measure.screenY)})`)
});
```

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 5000px;">
  <img src="https://jonalden.github.io/JonAldenPortfolio/assets/Images/astronaut_PNG69.png" style="transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);width: 100px;" />
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For moving an image diagonally you need to depend on y position as you are only scrolling for y in your page.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/m2uewboh/1/

Comment: This did the trick, thanks so much. Two follow up questions: whats the best way to limit the page height so the img doesn't keep scrolling forever down? And is there a way to slow down how fast the img grows?

Comment: All mathematics now and ratios you need to figure out total height of the page vs screen height n width :)

Answer (score 0):

To position the moving element in the background without having it scroll, I would use a `position: fixed` element as a frame (called `background` below) and then position the astronaut (called `rocket` below) relative to it.

All that's left to do is adjust the `margin` properties when the user scrolls. You might also want to add a `transition` to make it more smooth.
To make it get bigger, you can do that same thing with either the `width`/ `height` properties or with `transform: scale(...)`.

```css
#background {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#rocket {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  
  background: rgb(150, 200, 210);

  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
 <div id="rocket"></div>
</div>


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed. Faucibus purus in massa tempor nec feugiat nisl. Amet tellus cras adipiscing enim. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac. Sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in. Aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a. Vitae auctor eu augue ut. Dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus. Nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed. Donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed. Dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam.
Nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. A cras semper auctor neque. Duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt. Tempor id eu nisl nunc. Pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea.<br>
Nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. A cras semper auctor neque. Duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt. Tempor id eu nisl nunc. Pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea.<br>
Nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. A cras semper auctor neque. Duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt. Tempor id eu nisl nunc. Pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea.<br>
Nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. A cras semper auctor neque. Duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt. Tempor id eu nisl nunc. Pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique. Tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget. Nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea.
```